SSRS Keep grouping but merge data values
I have an SSRS report that contains 4 columns: Customer, Postcode, Date and Value.
Customer, Postcode and Date are my groups and Value is my data.
I want to end up with something that looks like the image below:
See example here
e.g. Customer A ordered £50 on 01/01/2024, £30 on 02/01/2024 and £20 on 03/04/2024, so has a total of £100. This is what I want to show, not the individual £50, £30, and £20.
I know how to get Customer and Postcode to appear every row (rather than merged because of the grouping), however I'm not sure how (or even if there's a way) to merge the overall value for Customer. Any help is appreciated :)

As you only need grouping at one end of the tablix then you can do this. It's not very intuitive but it's simple.
Create a table and add Date, PostCode and Customer in that order. Then add a parent group that groups by customer. This will add a group column at the start with the customer field already in place, change this to use the value column (so the expression will be =SUM(Fields!Value.Value) and adjust the header accordingly.
Finally, on the tablix properties, chenge the LayoutDirection property from LTR to RTL.
Here's a quick GIF to show you how I did it. (open in new tab to see it larger if required)


That's great, thank you! Do you know if it would be possible to do the same thing but with a matrix table, i.e. date as the columns? So the value would be merged for each customer and for each date?

You should ask a new question for this, show sample data (a text) and expected outcome. If this answer resolved this question then please mark it as accepted (the check mark to the left, under the vote up/down buttons). This helps other users find answers to similar questions.
